# Customize calculator (form) using for loop

Tags: php, forms, calculator

I have following code which works as form/calculator for bus rent price calculations and booking. This form contains fields like: day, month, time and other. I must say it is not my code, I just must customize it.

I need that when choosing a month, the number of days showing up in accordance with the month. For example, if it is February 2020, then in the appropriate  field there should be 29 days, and not 31 as it is now for all months, regardless of the choice. Same I need for all month with 30 days per month.

Here is part of my code where I need the changes:

```html
<?php 
echo "
<div><select id='diena' name='diena' onchange=\"document.getElementById('yo').innerHTML = '';\">
";
  for ($i=1; $i<32; $i++) echo "<option value='$i'". ($i == (date('d') + 1) ? ' selected' : '') .">$i</option>";
echo "
</select>
<select name='menesis' class='menesis' onchange=\"document.getElementById('yo').innerHTML = '';\">
";
  $m = array(1 => 'Janvāris', 'Februāris', 'Marts', 'Aprīlis', 'Maijs', 'Jūnijs', 'Jūlijs', 'Augusts', 'Septembris', 'Oktobris', 'Novembris', 'Decembris');
  $m2 = array(1 => 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
  $m3 = array(1 => 'январь', 'февраль', 'март', 'апрель', 'май', 'июнь', 'июль', 'август', 'сентябрь', 'октябрь', 'ноябрь', 'декабрь');
  $m4 = array(1 => 'Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'June', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
  
  if ($lang == '3') {
   for ($i=1; $i<13; $i++) echo "<option value='". $m2[$i] ."'". (isset($_POST['menesis']) ? ($_POST['menesis'] == $m2[$i] ? ' selected' : '') : ($i == date('m') ? ' selected' : '')) .">". ($i >= date('m') ? $m3[$i] .", ". date('Y') : $m3[$i] .", ". (date('Y')+1)) ."</option>";
  } elseif ($lang == '4') {
    for ($i=1; $i<13; $i++) echo "<option value='". $m2[$i] ."'". (isset($_POST['menesis']) ? ($_POST['menesis'] == $m2[$i] ? ' selected' : '') : ($i == date('m') ? ' selected' : '')) .">". ($i >= date('m') ? $m4[$i] .", ". date('Y') : $m4[$i] .", ". (date('Y')+1)) ."</option>";
  } elseif ($lang == '2') {
    for ($i=1; $i<13; $i++) echo "<option value='". $m2[$i] ."'". (isset($_POST['menesis']) ? ($_POST['menesis'] == $m2[$i] ? ' selected' : '') : ($i == date('m') ? ' selected' : '')) .">". ($i >= date('m') ? $m2[$i] .", ". date('Y') : $m2[$i] .", ". (date('Y')+1)) ."</option>";
  } else {
    for ($i=1; $i<13; $i++) echo "<option value='". $m2[$i] ."'". (isset($_POST['menesis']) ? ($_POST['menesis'] == $m2[$i] ? ' selected' : '') : ($i == date('m') ? ' selected' : '')) .">". ($i >= date('m') ? $m[$i] .", ". date('Y') : $m[$i] .", ". (date('Y')+1)) ."</option>";
  } 
echo "
</select>
<select name='laiks' onchange=\"document.getElementById('yo').innerHTML = '';\">
";
  for ($i=1; $i<25; $i++) echo "<option value='$i:00'". ($i == 9 ? ' selected' : '') .">". str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) .":00</option>";
echo "
</select>
</div>

<div><label for='diena2'></label> <select id='diena2' name='diena2' onchange=\"document.getElementById('yo').innerHTML = '';\">
";
  for ($i=1; $i<32; $i++) echo "<option value='$i'". ($i == (date('d') + 1) ? ' selected' : '') .">$i</option>";
echo "
</select>
<select name='menesis2' class='menesis' onchange=\"document.getElementById('yo').innerHTML = '';\">
";
  if ($lang == '3') {
    for ($i=1; $i<13; $i++) echo "<option value='". $m2[$i] ."'". (isset($_POST['menesis']) ? ($_POST['menesis'] == $m2[$i] ? ' selected' : '') : ($i == date('m') ? ' selected' : '')) .">". ($i >= date('m') ? $m3[$i] .", ". date('Y') : $m3[$i] .", ". (date('Y')+1)) ."</option>";
  } elseif ($lang == '4') {
    for ($i=1; $i<13; $i++) echo "<option value='". $m2[$i] ."'". (isset($_POST['menesis']) ? ($_POST['menesis'] == $m2[$i] ? ' selected' : '') : ($i == date('m') ? ' selected' : '')) .">". ($i >= date('m') ? $m4[$i] .", ". date('Y') : $m4[$i] .", ". (date('Y')+1)) ."</option>";
  } elseif ($lang == '2') {
    for ($i=1; $i<13; $i++) echo "<option value='". $m2[$i] ."'". (isset($_POST['menesis']) ? ($_POST['menesis'] == $m2[$i] ? ' selected' : '') : ($i == date('m') ? ' selected' : '')) .">". ($i >= date('m') ? $m2[$i] .", ". date('Y') : $m2[$i] .", ". (date('Y')+1)) ."</option>";
  } else {
    for ($i=1; $i<13; $i++) echo "<option value='". $m2[$i] ."'". (isset($_POST['menesis']) ? ($_POST['menesis'] == $m2[$i] ? ' selected' : '') : ($i == date('m') ? ' selected' : '')) .">". ($i >= date('m') ? $m[$i] .", ". date('Y') : $m[$i] .", ". (date('Y')+1)) ."</option>";
  }
echo "
</select>
<select name='laiks2' onchange=\"document.getElementById('yo').innerHTML = '';\">
";
  for ($i=1; $i<25; $i++) echo "<option value='$i:00'". ($i == 9 ? ' selected' : '') .">". str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) .":00</option>";
echo "
</select>
</div>

 </div>

</div>";
?>
```

Hope I will find help here.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _“Hope I will find help here.”_ - that requires first of all, that you describe to us what your specific _problem_ with this is, just dropping off your mere requirement here is not enough.

Comment: Try using carbon library where you can get picked month days etc...

Comment: 04FS: Hi, next time I will definitely reread the rules. So, sorry if my text was prepared wrong from my side. May be it looks like requirements, but for me it is a problem. I experimenting with ifs and else, use some snippets, but nothing helps. How I said I am total beginner at php.

Comment: Lerner, thank you for the recommendation I will check.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your code is poorly written and I didn't fully read it, you could just try to use input type date for offering a date picker. If you need time as well u can simply add another input type time.

```html
<input type="date" id="start" name="booking-start"
       value="2018-07-22">
       
<input type="date" id="end" name="booking-end"
       value="2018-07-28">
```

Comment: Aaron: thank you, but unfortunately I must leave at frontend the same form element as it is in code, I can change only functionality.